# Create list name dynamically?

Tags: python

Let's say I have multiple lists called `level_1`, `level_2`, `level_3`.. Now I want to loop through all of them, but want to use list 1 on idx 1, list 2 on idx 2, .. My solution would be something like this:

```
for idx, level in enumerate(??): -- #Don't know what to insert here
    if idx == 1:
        print(level[0])
    elif idx == 2:
        print(level[1])
```

Is there a way to create the list name you're enumerating through dynamically? Like this:

```
for idx, level in enumerate(level_+idx):
    print(level[0])
    print(level[1])
```

Comment: just put your lists in a list

Comment: There is, but this is actually bad design. The only good way to do it, is either prevent yourself from getting that many lists (put these in a list, dictionary,...) or by constructing a list `enumerate([level_1,level_2,...])`.

Comment: Don't do that. Put all the lists in another list. Dynamically creating variables is almost always the wrong thing to do.

Comment: Don't do this. Just *use another container to hold your lists*. `for idx, level in enumerate((list1,list2,list3,list4)): ...`

Comment: The non-insane way of dealing with situations like this is to use a list of lists, rather than dynamically generating variable names.

Comment: Thank you all. Helped me a lot :) I'm completely new to python and it's not as easy as I thought ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list which contains all of the lists and `loop` through it instead of using multiple if/else statements, for example:

```
big_list = [level_1, level_2, level_3]
for i, lst in enumerate(big_list):
    print lst[i]
```